# Performing a function over multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have defined a function. This is called 'bisection' and the code for this is beneath the post.

I also have a dataframe I called 'v', that contains 7 columns and 2 rows:

```
D   P   h     O   Q   SD      LT
80  27  0.37 50   2    3      1.51
50  27  0.25 50   2    3      0.03
```

You see in the bisection function that I need four parameters. f, a, b and N. 
These are defined as followed:

```
b = 5
a = 0.05
N = 1000
```

now, 'f' is a function with a unknown variable in: 'x'. It's an anonymous function (lambda x). The bisection-function finds the value of 'x', where f equals zero. Now, 'f' is a really nasty derivative, and yes, I'll clean it up, but please do not focus on that, because the function itself is correct. so, 'f' is:

```
f = lambda x: norm.ppf(1-(v.iloc[i,4]*v.iloc[i,1]*v.iloc[i,2])/(2*v.iloc[i,0]*x))*v.iloc[i,5]*np.sqrt(v.iloc[i,6])*v.iloc[i,1]*v.iloc[i,2]+np.sqrt(2*v.iloc[i,0]*v.iloc[i,3]*v.iloc[i,1]*v.iloc[i,2])-v.iloc[i,0]*x*(((-(norm.ppf(1-(v.iloc[i,4]*v.iloc[i,2]*v.iloc[i,1])/(2*x*v.iloc[i,0]))))*(1-norm.cdf((norm.ppf(1-(v.iloc[i,4]*v.iloc[i,2]*v.iloc[i,1])/(2*x*v.iloc[i,0]))),loc=0,scale=1))+(norm.pdf((norm.ppf(1-(v.iloc[i,4]*v.iloc[i,2]*v.iloc[i,1])/(2*x*v.iloc[i,0]))),loc=0,scale=1)))*v.iloc[i,5]*np.sqrt(v.iloc[i,6])-v.iloc[i,4])/v.iloc[i,4]*-1
```

The goal is to apply the 'bisection-function' to every row in the dataframe: thus adding a new column that gives the result of the bisection-function for every row, where the function uses all the 7 columns.

Now, when I want to apply the function 'bisection(f, a, b, N)', I tried the following code:

```
  for i in range(0,2,1):
      v['k'] = bisection(f,a,b,N)
```

This gives me the following result:

```
D   P   h     O       Q SD  LT    k
80  27  0.37  50     2  3   1.51 3.814891
50  27  0.25  50     2  3   0.03 3.814891
```

As you can see, it finds the right value for 'x', but only for the second row. The result for the first row is 4.50.. and when I change the code to:

```
  for i in range(0,1,1):
      v['k'] = bisection(f,a,b,N)
```

I get:

```
D   P   h     O      Q  SD  LT    k
80  27  0.37  50     2  3   1.51 4.503648
50  27  0.25  50     2  3   0.03 4.503648
```

So the result I want is:

```
D   P   h     O      Q  SD  LT    k
80  27  0.37  50     2  3   1.51 4.503648
50  27  0.25  50     2  3   0.03 3.814891
```

How do I achieve this?

I also tried by changing 'f' to:

```
f = lambda x: norm.ppf(1-(v.Q*v.P*v.h)/(2*v.D*x))*v.SD*np.sqrt(v.LT)*v.P*v.h+np.sqrt(2*v.D*v.O*v.P*v.h)-v.D*x*(((-(norm.ppf(1-(v.Q*v.P*v.h)/(2*x*v.D))))*(1-norm.cdf((norm.ppf(1-(v.Q*v.P*v.h)/(2*x*v.D))),loc=0,scale=1))+(norm.pdf((norm.ppf(1-(v.Q*v.P*v.h)/(2*x*v.D))),loc=0,scale=1)))*v.SD*np.sqrt(v.LT)-v.Q)/v.Q*-1
```

And tried to iterate with this code:

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
     v.append(bisection(f,a,b,N))
```

But then I get the error:

```
  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
  a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Anyone can help me?

The code for the bisection function:

```
def bisection(f,a,b,N):
'''Approximate solution of f(x)=0 on interval [a,b] by the bisection 
method.

Parameters
----------
f : function
    The function for which we are trying to approximate a solution f(x)=0.
a,b : numbers
    The interval in which to search for a solution. The function returns
    None if f(a)*f(b) >= 0 since a solution is not guaranteed.
N : (positive) integer
    The number of iterations to implement.

Returns
-------
x_N : number
    The midpoint of the Nth interval computed by the bisection method. The
    initial interval [a_0,b_0] is given by [a,b]. If f(m_n) == 0 for some
    midpoint m_n = (a_n + b_n)/2, then the function returns this solution.
    If all signs of values f(a_n), f(b_n) and f(m_n) are the same at any
    iteration, the bisection method fails and return None.

Examples
--------
>>> f = lambda x: x**2 - x - 1
>>> bisection(f,1,2,25)
1.618033990263939
>>> f = lambda x: (2*x - 1)*(x - 3)
>>> bisection(f,0,1,10)
0.5
'''
if f(a)*f(b) >= 0:
    print("Bisection method fails.")
    return None
a_n = a
b_n = b
for n in range(1,N+1):
    m_n = (a_n + b_n)/2
    f_m_n = f(m_n)
    if f(a_n)*f_m_n < 0:
        a_n = a_n
        b_n = m_n
    elif f(b_n)*f_m_n < 0:
        a_n = m_n
        b_n = b_n
    elif f_m_n == 0:
        print("Found exact solution.")
        return m_n
    else:
        print("Bisection method fails.")
        return None
return (a_n + b_n)/2
```

Comment: Please share the full Traceback error.

Comment: The question and the code are very confusing (at least for me). Making it simpler is not "besides the question", it will help other people understand your problem. After cleaning up, you might find the answer yourself (like cleaning your room and finding that thing you were looking for). By sharing confusing code and a confusing question, you are decreasing the probability of someone being able to help you. If people insist in telling you this, as annoying as it is, maybe you should listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code:

```
    for i in range(0,2,1):
        v['k'] = bisection(f,a,b,N)
```

just sets ALL of the new column 'k' to whatever value is calculated by the bisection function in each iteration

create a series and assign it to new row 'k', maybe like this:

```
    v['k'] = pd.Series([bisection(f,a,b,N) for i in range(2)], index = v.index)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandalaphon ! But now I got an indexerror: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds...:s

Comment: Index the series similarly to the dataframe (I added index = v.index to the suggested answer)